# MacでMySQLが起動しません。　多くの人が直面する /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Air.local.pidです・・・

Tags: mysql, macos

Mac OS 環境にLaravel, MySQLを導入しているのですがうまく行きません。
`brew install mysql` でMySQL 5.xを導入したのですがうまくいきません。
Mac でmySQL を使うための何か良い代替案ないでしょうか？
ローカル環境のLaravelから接続して使いたいのですが・・・

```shell
% sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)

% brew services
Name Status User Plist
mysql@5.7 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist

% sudo /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start

Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Air.local.pid).

touch /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Air.local.pid

% sudo /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql.server start

Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/MacBook-Air.local.pid).
```

Comment: 何か`sudo`は使ってはいけないようですが。[.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/＊＊＊＊.local.pid)が出たときの解決法について](https://teratail.com/questions/263973), [ERROR! The server quit without updating PID fileを解決したい](https://teratail.com/questions/295270) 一度使ってしまったらアンインストール/再インストールが簡単なようですね。

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mysql -u root`しただけなら、何もファイルは作成されていないと思うので

```
mysql.server start
```

で大丈夫なのではないでしょうか?

Answer (score -1):

MySQLは、Macのローカル環境ではつかえなかったと思います。
linuxの仮想環境を作りましょう。